# Select MIN on Primary Key Field Using Sub-Optimal Index / Plan

Tags: index, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

I have a stored procedure that takes in a list (table variable) of IDs, and then it performs some queries to analyze the contents of the list and take the appropriate actions. One of the queries checks to see if the IDs are in a table by comparing the IDs to the minimum ID of the table's primary key.

I've got:

```
DECLARE @tableNameID IDTableType --custom user table type with one field: ID
```

and the table definition is like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbTableName (
   KeyIDField INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   OtherField INT,
   ...)
```

In addition to the clustered index on the primary key field, there's a nonclustered index built on OtherField.

The particular line of code being executed is:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbTableNameID WHERE ID < (SELECT MIN(KeyIDField) FROM tbTableName (NOLOCK)) AND ID > 0)
```

As you can see from the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ09QiH2c), the engine is electing to use the nonclustered index to scan the table and calculate the minimum KeyIDField across four parallel streams, gather the four streams, and then pick the minimum from the four values. This should be a simple dive down the clustered index to pick off the first value. What's going on?

Notes:
The clustered PK index is less than .5% fragmented, and the stats were updated at 5 AM.
The nonclustered index is less than .6% fragmented, and the stats were updated at 4 AM (when the index was rebuilt during maintenance).

Running the query on its own I can get the query to produce the expected query plan.

In the same procedure, prior to this query, there is another check:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OtherField) FROM tbTableName (NOLOCK) WHERE KeyIDField IN (SELECT ID FROM @tableNameID)
```

This query was also using the nonclustered index, when it would make more sense to seek on the clustered index and join to the contents of the table variable. I'm wondering if there was some sort of hangover from this query running into the other one, or if they were both getting hung up from SQL Server caching a partial query plan from a similar query.

I'm not opposed to adding query hints, but I'm struggling to reason out why the clustered index would be passed over in this case.

EDIT (07/21/22):
Something else that may be worth mentioning - the server was under heavy CPU load during this time, and it was reporting a high amount of SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits. I read some more about that [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/increased-sos_scheduler_yield-waits-on-virtual-machines/) and [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/cpu-ready-impact-on-sos_scheduler_yield/), and then confirmed with IT that our CPU Ready % stats were above the 5%  level cited by Jonathan as the threshold for expected performance degradation. Is it possible that the engine is running out of time waiting to try to build a query plan, and it just throws together some nonsense?

Comment: You may find some helpful information here: [Performance Issues With EXISTS Queries In SQL Server](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/performance-issues-with-exists-queries/)

Comment: @ErikDarling I didn't document my research well enough, but I thought that I was able to reproduce the bad query plan outside of an IF EXISTS. Even so, I'd like to implement this to prevent recurrences. Would you recommend this as a general rule - don't perform queries inside of IF statements? Or is it specifically IF EXISTS that cause problems?

Comment: you should test with a temp table instead of table variable. The poor estimates/lack of statistics often create poor plan choices, especially when correlated to large tables.